# SQL where query removing unintended rows

Tags: sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    e.Id, MAX(r.EventId), MAX(r.UserId), 
    e.Name, MAX(r.Description)
FROM Events e 
LEFT JOIN Results r ON e.Id = r.EventId
GROUP BY e.Id, e.Name;
```

It correctly outputs this result set:

[image]

However, when I add a where clause so it doesn't include userID 86, it removes most rows as you can see below in the image below. What I'm trying to do is so that it only removes row with 86 as the UserId.

[image]

This is the code with where clause:

```
SELECT
    e.Id, MAX(r.EventId), MAX(r.UserId), 
    e.Name, MAX(r.Description)
FROM 
    Events e 
LEFT JOIN 
    Results r ON e.Id = r.EventId
WHERE
    r.UserId != 86 
GROUP BY
    e.Id, e.Name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the extra predicate in the `ON` clause, as in:

```
Select e.Id, max(r.EventId), max(r.UserId), e.Name, max(r.Description)
FROM Events e LEFT JOIN Results r
ON e.Id = r.EventId AND r.UserId <> 86 
group by e.Id, e.Name;
```